# Process Builder Scenarios

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, process-builder

this weekend i cleared my Salesforce App Builder certification.  I will now further my studies in apex and lightning, learning the programmatic side but i would also like to be an expert of the declarative side of development.

Wanted to ask everyone if they knew of practice scenarios i could use in a developer org, with the Lightning process builder. Flows has a workbook that I can review but i don't see anything for the process builder.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't go wrong with trailhead for this: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/business_process_automation

Comment: thanks Peter.  i did the trailhead module but was looking for other examples/scenarios where i could create a process with process builder.

Comment: kind of answered my own question here but in case someone would like examples or practice with creating flows or using process builder click this link:   https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/learning-process-builder/

Comment: You can post your own answer @Chad. Although you may need a minimum reputation. You could at least give it a shot.